# Hadoop Pig Max Command

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have one file that contains data of all the countries from all over the world.

I want to find out the country which has maximum airport.

I have written below code:

```
A = load 'airports.dat' USING PigStorage (',') AS(AirportID:int,Name:chararray,City:chararray,Country:chararray,IATA:chararray,IATAothers:chararray,Latitude:float,Longitude:float,Altitude:float,Timezone:float,DST:chararray,Zone:chararray);
B= GROUP A BY Country;
C= FOREACH B GENERATE A.Country, COUNT(A) AS Count;
```

but after this I am not getting how to find the maximum.

Can anybody please help.

Comment: MAX "Computes the maximum of the numeric values or chararrays in a single-column bag.", so it operates on values, not whole columns. You have to ORDER DESC and LIMIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the number of airports per country. What you need to do now, is take the row with the highest number:

```
D = order C by $1 DESC;
E = limit D 1;
dump E;
```

Comment: Thanks ran....                                                   The output is like ({(india),(india),(india)....and so on},25)

Comment: What needs to be done if i want the output as (india,25) only

Comment: Instead of generate A.Country, you should generate group as Country. When you do a groupby, you actually get a relation of groupkey|all rows belonging to that group. When you generate A.country, it will give you the country of each of those rows. What you need is they group key (which is retrieved simply using 'for each B generate group, COUNT(A)'